# Custom NumberPicker - optimization

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder, numberpicker

I have this NUMBERPICKER.
But I don't want the numbers in the box to show up in the section_room until selected one. Until that I want to have a backgroudImage (placeholder).

```html
<div class="section_room">
  <select id="persons" type="text" placeholder="" onchange="hideIcon(this);">
    <option value="null">1</option>
    <option value="null">2</option>         
    <option value="null">3</option>
    <option value="null">4</option>
  </select>
</div>

    <script>
      function hideIcon(self) {
        self.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
      }
    </script>
```

```css
#persons {
    background-image: url(../images/icn_person1_dark.png);
    background-size: 40% 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
select {
    float:right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 44px;
    color: #858585;
    font-size: 0.8725em;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-color:darkgrey;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
}
select option {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having, specifically? Your script should not be placed inside of your `<select>` element, as well.

Comment: My problem is that the section_room always have the number 1 and I want it to have a backgroudImage (placeholder), until I select a number.

Comment: @JoãoGuerreiro check out the answer below.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald did and I already answer it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<option disabled selected value></option>
```

Which will provide a 'blank' selection until someone chooses one of the available numbers.

EDIT: Nevermind. Image in a select option is an awful idea.

View here: [Updated JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/p3b93dyu/3/)

Your full `<select>` would look like this:

```
<select id="persons" type="text" placeholder="" onchange="hideIcon(this);">
  <option disabled selected value></option>
  <option value="null">1</option>
  <option value="null">2</option>         
  <option value="null">3</option>
  <option value="null">4</option>
</select>
```

The Select2 plugin's template feature can handle this:
[Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#themes-templating-responsive-design)

Comment: It worked, but there is a better way to do it?
This way I'll get a blank space in the number selection list.

Comment: For exemple, is there a way to hide the number 1 until a number is selected? And until then the backgroudImage (placeholder) would be visible.

Comment: It's not something that's actually supported, as far as I know.

Comment: The `<select>` element wasn't meant to hold images at all. Having the non-selectable blank space in the number list may be the trade-ff to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your advises.
Can you suggest another way to do this without the <select> element and with the background or placeholder element? @GlenDespaux

Comment: If you really need it to work in this way, you may want to look into the Select2 library, which has a template feature to allow images. I've added the link in my answer.